# GitHub выдает ошибку

Tags: git, github

> ```
> Commit failed - exit code 128 received, with output: '*** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
>   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
> Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'User@DESKTOP-CA2F2PA.(none)')'
> ```

---

Как это исправить? Я ничего не понимаю, вроде бы в настройках GitHub сделал публичный email, перезагружал комп, и не помогало.

Answer (score 4):

Первое, что вам следует сделать после установки Git - указать ваше имя и адрес электронной почты. Это важно, потому что каждый коммит в Git содержит эту информацию, и она включена в коммиты, передаваемые вами, и не может быть далее изменена:

Для этого в консоли выполите следующие комманды:

```
git config --global user.name "Vasya Pupkin"
git config --global user.email "vasya.pupkin@email.com"
```

[Первоначальная настройка Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)

> ```
> Commit failed - exit code 128 received, with output: '*** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
>   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
> Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'User@DESKTOP-CA2F2PA.(none)')'
> ```

В ошибке прямо это и написано если причитаться =)